# Why are objects passed by value modified as if they are passed by reference?

Tags: c#

For example,

```
  class Age
  {
    public int Year
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public Age(int year)
    {
      Year = year;
    }
  }

  class Person
  {
    public Age MyAge
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public Person(Age age)
    {
      age.Year = ( age.Year * 2 );
      MyAge = age;      
    }
  }
```

[Client]

```
Age a = new Age(10);
Person p = new Person( a );
```

When a new `Age` class is constructed the `Year` property is: 10.  However, the Person class changes the Year to 20, even though there is no ref keyword...

Can someone explain why Year is not still 10?

Comment: A reference to the object is passed by value.

Comment: You are not changing the reference itself but the internal state of the object it points to.

Comment: Because C# uses [*Call By (Object) Sharing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)   (for reference-typed parameters, when neither `out` nor `ref` are used). An implicit copy/clone/duplicate is *not* done (for reference-typed parameters) and the variables (in both locations) evaluate to the *same object* ..

Comment: (Where "reference-typed parameter" means the type [of the parameter] is that of an Interface or a Class, but not of a Struct. Boxing/unboxing also factors in, but ..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference to the object is passed by value.  With that reference, the object instance itself can be modified.

Consider the following example to understand what that statement means:

```
public class A
{
    private MyClass my = new MyClass();

    public void Do()
    {
        TryToChangeInstance(my);
        DoChangeInstance(my);
        DoChangeProperty(my);
    }

    private void TryToChangeInstance(MyClass my)
    {
        // The copy of the reference is replaced with a new reference.
        // The instance assigned to my goes out of scope when the method exits.
        // The original instance is unaffected.
        my = new MyClass(); 
    }

    private void DoChangeInstance(ref MyClass my)
    {
        // A reference to the reference was passed in
        // The original instance is replaced by the new instance.
        my = new MyClass(); 
    }

    private void DoChangeProperty(MyClass my)
    {
        my.SomeProperty = 42; // This change survives the method exit.
    }
}
```

Comment: [References are not addresses.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx) But other than that, yeah.

Comment: True.  I simplify.  They are really pointers to addresses to enable GC.  Still, I'll update to be more accurate.

Comment: "Pointers to addresses" does not make sense, but whatever. Why do you feel the need to bring in addresses and pointers? It's a reference, that reference is copied, period.

Comment: @delnan I wish we didn't even have to talk about references (at a conceptual level) ..

Comment: @pst How so? Value types can only do that much.

Comment: @delnan No, I mean, we can still say "Reference Types" (although perhaps more clear, "Class Types"? "Non-Struct Types?"), but then not *need* talk about References at a lower level. For instance, JavaScript doesn't have the term "reference" (well, it does, but for a bindable *l-value* situation) in the specification at all, yet it has the same Call By [Object] Sharing semantics.

Comment: @pst Well, the spec may not have the term, but *some* term is needed (or at least useful) for such a vital concept when you explain it to newbs all day. And "reference" specifically is so common that it's often seen in this question's JS equivalent. Also, "reference type" is clearer than "class type" IMHO -- objects of a reference types are always accessed through references. "Class type" makes me think of metaclasses which don't even exist in C#. "Evaluates to" is confusing IMHO, because it does not specify whether I get a copy of it, or a indirect handle (if yo dislike "reference") on it.

Comment: @delnan See, there we go, talking in terms of "references": "access through references". But they are *not*. They (objects) are accessed through expressions (e.g. variables) which evaluate to (or name) objects .. but yeah, it's semantics, as long as all parties involved can agree.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15399/discussion-between-delnan-and-pst)

Comment: @delnan: The CLR does not use physical memory addresses directly to point to object instances (the way C++ does) because doing so would lead to the classic heap fragmentation problem.  Instead, it uses (in C/C++ terminology) a pointer to that address.  An additional level of indirection.  A pointer-pointer.  That way, the original memory can be rearranged by the GC in the processes address space to reduce heap fragmentation, while the program can continue to use the original reference/handle/pointer-pointer to refer to the object instance.

Comment: @EricJ. I'm pretty certain that's not how it happens -- my references (darn, did it again) include the very blog post by Eric Lippert is linked to in the first comment. Objects can be moved  (for compaction or for other purposes) regardless of how you implement references; with direct pointers you just have to find all locations that use that pointer. That's wasteful at GC time, but double indirection hurts the cache and adds even more overhead to reference types and dereferencing *all the time* for *all* objects.

Comment: @delnan: I stand corrected.  Must have been thinking of either an earlier .NET implementation, or perhaps a Java implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Because `Age` is a *reference* type.

Comment: OP wouldn't be the first to misunderstand that term, so better add a explanation of what that means.